# Routing - Spring Boot Web App & AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, elastic-load-balancer

I have a Spring Boot web app with the usual routings:

```
@GetMapping("/account")
public String search(@RequestParam(value="search"...
```

I've now deployed this behind an AWS Application Load Balancer, where I have used path based routing to target my app.

I've configured `/admin/*` on the Load Balancer to forward to my app, which works fine.

The issue though is that my app is now seeing `/admin/account`, rather than the `/account` it is expecting.

AWS says:

> Note that the path pattern is used to route requests but does not
>   alter them. For example, if a rule has a path pattern of /img/*, the
>   rule would forward a request for /img/picture.jpg to the specified
>   target group as a request for /img/picture.jpg.

Is there any tidy way around this? Or do I have to resort to something like this:

```
@GetMapping("*/account")
```

Comment: I don't think that functionality exists in AWS loadbalancer -- check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317685

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that functionality exists in AWS Applicxation loadbalancer -- check this out stackoverflow.com/questions/39317685

Quoting the relevant part here

> you can use a reverse proxy on your server and do something like this
>   (this is Nginx configuration):
>
> ```
> server {
>   listen 80 default_server;
>
>   location /secured/ {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:{service_port}/;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This will strip the /admin part and proxy everything else to your
>   service. Just be sure to have the trailing / after the service port.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of doing (besides web server url rewrites or a reverse proxy like Zuul) is to do the url rewrites within your app.

An easy way to do that is using UrlRewriteFilter

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean urlRewriteFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistration.setFilter(new UrlRewriteFilter());

    // You probably want to set the order very low so it fires before
    // other filters, especially if you're using Spring Security
    filterRegistration.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

    filterRegistration.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/*"));

    Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();
    initParams.put("confPath", "url_rewrite.xml");

    filterRegistration.setInitParameters(initParams);

    return filterRegistration;
}
```

The maven coordinates for the filter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

A configuration file example can be found here: http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/urlrewrite.xml