# AWS redirect in Load Balancer to work with POST and PUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to do something similar to this: [Create AWS Application Load Balancer Rule which trim off request's prefix without using additional reverse proxy like nginx, httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317685/create-aws-application-load-balancer-rule-which-trim-off-requests-prefix-withou?rq=1)

Using AWS Load balancer, to redirect traffic from URL say `/foo` to `/bar` like this:

[image]

But only GET requests are routed correctly and POST,PUT,etc get routed as GET so I'm getting an error because my controller doesn't have those GET methods.

Is there a way to do this with AWS load balancer?

The question I linked is from 2016 so I was hoping something has changed in 5 years.

Comment: The redirect you show is telling the browser to make a new request to a different URL; it is the browser (following the HTTP standard) which is deciding to make that a GET request.

Comment: So how can I make it keep the original request type? @IMSoP

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using a client written in Golang, this is why redirected `POST` requests end up as `GET` on the server side:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18570
https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/net/http/client.go;l=514

Answer (score 0):

In the section in which you define the condition you have to specify the http method, otherwise it will consider GET as default.

Example for the OPTIONS HTTP calls
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895672) is mainly due to how the HTTP status code 301 and 302 works with the client that is sending the request, which are the available redirection status code for the Application Load Balancer Listener Rule. so unfortunately we are limited with what AWS provides as status code, but as a different solution if the library or tool you are using as a client allows it you could implement a custom behaviour in your application to allow a different handling of the 301 and 302 status code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **/*** in the IF section with a path as a condition.

For example, IF /* THEN Redirect to.

Additionally, you can use one of more condition in the IF section such as host-header, http-request-method, query-string, source-ip

Comment: then all traffic will be redirected to that, I have more conditions there it's not the only one.

Comment: You can add multiple rules in that case and multiple conditions for each rule.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) blog. Aggregate these cases according to requirement.

Answer (score -2):

there's http `request methode option`
[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8zlM.png)

you can put there PUT or POST or GET like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2LX0.png)